# How to delete pattern which matches with the next new pattern which is calling in the next line by using /bin/sed command in dc_shell

Tags: perl, sed, tcl

Below is the example of my file,

```
         signal {
          {
            ab
            cd
          }

        "m_1_clk" {
              P {
                 '0ns' D;
                  '25ns' U;
                  '65ns' D;
                  }
             }

            "m_0_clk" {
                        P {
                          '0ns' D;
                          '25ns' U;
                          '65ns' D;
                          }
                       }

              "o_[9]" {
                     Data S Mk {
                     Active Up;
                            }
                        }

               "m_0_clk" {
                          Data S Mk {
                            Active Up;
                            }
                        }

             "m_1_clk" {
                          Data S Mk {
                          Active Up;
                            }
                        }
            }
```

I am expecting the output from above file to be:

```
      signal {
           {
              ab
              cd
            }
         "o_[9]" {
                  Data S Mk {
                  Active Up;
                      }
                   }
              }
```

Hi,
Above is the example of my file
    I would like to delete pattern which matches the next pattern which is calling in the next line.

Trying to search the specific pattern for deleting the lines which it should not be present in my file.

Need to search the specific pattern with new pattern in the next line. because first line is calling in multiple loops. so should grep specific pattern of all the content.
I tried using the below command in tcl its not working. could anyone help me on this,

below is the sed command used in tcl

```
exec /bin/sed -e {s/\m\(.*\)clk" {\.*\n\.*Data\.*//}  -i file

exec /bin/sed -e {s/\m\(.*\)clk" {\.*\n\.*P {\.*//}  -i  file
```

Comment: I think we need some desired output. I also think that `regex` might not be the tool for the job, because this looks like a contextual search.

Comment: Please explain the criteria for keeping the "o_[9]" block but discarding the "m_*_clk" blocks.

Comment: added some logic and created some ports in the design to do some modification but end of the design I am trying to remove the ports which I have created in the design. So only "m_*_clk" blocks are not needed

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.(Considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown sample file)

```
awk -v line_number=$(cat Input_file | wc -l) '/signal {/ || /"o_\[9\]" {/ || FNR==line_number{flag=1}; /^$/{flag=""} flag'    Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for code too now as follows:

```
awk -v line_number=$(cat Input_file | wc -l) '   ##Creating variable named line_number in awk script whose value is number of lines of Input_file.
/signal {/ || /"o_\[9\]" {/ || FNR==line_number{ ##checking condition here if a line contains strings either signal {  OR "o_\[9\]" { then do following:
  flag=1}                                        ##Setting variable named flag here and setting its value to 1 here.
/^$/{                                            ##Checking condition here if a line is NULL or BLANK then do following:
  flag=""}                                       ##Nullifying the variable flag here.
flag                                             ##awk works on method of condition then actions, so checking if variable flag value is NOT NULL here and not mentioning any action here so by default peint of current line will happen here.
'   Input_file                                   ##Metioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: You forgot the last `}` from the `signal` block.

Comment: @daxim, thanks a TON sir, I edited my one liner now, will edit explanation part too shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with a context-sensitive parser:

```
use Marpa::R2 qw();

my $input = <<'INPUT';
         signal {
          {
            ab
            cd
          }

        "m_1_clk" {
              P {
                 '0ns' D;
                  '25ns' U;
                  '65ns' D;
                  }
             }

            "m_0_clk" {
                        P {
                          '0ns' D;
                          '25ns' U;
                          '65ns' D;
                          }
                       }

              "o_[9]" {
                     Data S Mk {
                     Active Up;
                            }
                        }

               "m_0_clk" {
                          Data S Mk {
                            Active Up;
                            }
                        }

             "m_1_clk" {
                          Data S Mk {
                          Active Up;
                            }
                        }
            }
INPUT

my $grammar = Marpa::R2::Scanless::G->new({
    bless_package => 'Foo',
    source => \<<'GRAMMAR',
        :default ::= action => [values] bless => ::lhs
        lexeme default = action => [ value ] bless => ::name latm => 1
        :start ::= blocks
        blocks ::= block+
        block ::= optionalname [{] contentblocks [}] optionalws
        optionalname ::= name | epsilon
        contentblocks ::= contentorblock+
        contentorblock ::= content | block
        name ~ [a-zA-Z0-9_"\x{5b}\x{5d} ]+
        content ~ [a-zA-Z0-9;'\s]*
        optionalws ~ [\s]*
        epsilon ::=
GRAMMAR
});

my $parser = Marpa::R2::Scanless::R->new({grammar => $grammar});
$parser->read(\$input);
my $output;
deleteblocks($parser->value->$*);
print $output;

sub deleteblocks {
    my ($v) = @_;
    return if ref $v eq 'Foo::block' and $v->[0][0]
        and $v->[0][0][0] !~ /signal|"o_\[9\]"/;
    if (ref $v) {
        deleteblocks($_) for $v->@*;
    } else {
        $output .= $v || '';
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
     signal {
      {
        ab
        cd
      }

    "o_[9]" {
                 Data S Mk {
                 Active Up;
                        }
                    }

           }
```